# linux mint crashed after updating nvidia driver

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, cinnamon

I'm using linux mint 18 cinnamon-64bit and after updating nvidia driver and rebooting an error message say "Cinnamon just crashed. You are currently running in Fallback Mode."
I do this to update the driver:

```
system setting -> Driver manager then selected nvidia-378
```

[image]

What is the reason to rebooting into fallback mode? and How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you edit your Question and show `dkms status` and `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2` also `uname -r`

Comment: Here is the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your `lspci` shows that you are not using the nvidia drivers, but the nouveau drivers (the open sources ones).

You should see the procedure i've written in this ticket, it should perfectly fit for your case (it's the exact same problem)

[Switch from 'nouveau' drivers to the 'nvidia' proprietary ones](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352828/how-to-switch-nvidia-driver-from-nouveau-to-nvidia-proprietary/353022#353022)

After following this procedure, show us again the result of your `lspci`.
You should then have a driver like this:
`Kernel driver in use: nvidia`

Comment: It show that because i select the intel gpu again to exit from the fallback mode and if i select nvidia the problem occurs again.

Comment: When you select nvidia, does the kernel driver in use is still "nouveau" ?
Anyway, you should really try to put the proprietary drivers correctly, i had tons of crashes before having them correctly installed.

Comment: I switch to nvidia right now and guess what?!!, it reboot normally not into fallback mode but kernel driver in use is still `nouveau` as you say.

Comment: when i run `service mdm stop` nothing happen just black screen with this `38.264619] nouveau 0000:08:00.0 priv: HUB0 : 10ecc0 ffffffff (1e70822c)` at the top left corner.

Comment: You need to be in console mode: `ctrl-alt-f1`
This command stop your graphical interface. If you do it while you're using this same graphical interface ... you're gonna loose it.
Press `ctrl-alt-f1`, you'll have a black screen, with `login` displayed. Log on with your usual login / password, and follow the procedure.

Comment: Yes i did these steps and when i ran `service mdm stop` in consol mode i got that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Deinstall the current Nvidia-driver.  Over driver-manager.

It seems you have includet a ppa? `sudo apt install ppa-purge`  Please take a look to[man ppa-purge](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ppa-purge.1.html) to remove it. `sudo ppa-purge -o graphics-drivers`  after that `sudo apt update && sudo apt install  nvidia-367`

Comment: I'm new with linux, could you please explain more details

Comment: Show `apt-cache policy nvidia-378` so I know the source from the package.

Comment: gives me this result `nvidia-378:Installed: 378.13-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.3 Candidate: 378.13-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.3 Version table:***378.13-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.3 500 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages 100 /var/lib/dpkg/statu`

Comment: ping edit my answer